# Eclipse: An error occurred loading the SSH2 private keys

Tags: eclipse, ssh

I am using eclipse Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0) on macOS Mojave Version 10.14.1. I followed the instruction on https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.9/user/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/ to set up ssh keys for GitHub. I am able to "git clone" the repository in the terminal with no problem. However, when it came to eclipse, an exception occurred:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: git@github.***.com:EA/entity-matching.git: invalid private key: [B@47822527
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.ListRemoteOperation.run(ListRemoteOperation.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.SourceBranchPage$8.run(SourceBranchPage.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: git@github.***.com:EA/entity-matching.git: invalid privatekey: [B@47822527
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:200)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@47822527
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:664)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:561)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.IdentityFile.newInstance(IdentityFile.java:40)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:407)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getJSch(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.EclipseSshSessionFactory.createSession(EclipseSshSessionFactory.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.createSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:138)
    ... 8 more
```

I am sure the URI is correct. My ~/.ssh/congif is

```
Host *
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 UseKeychain yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Can anybody help me on this please?

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: General > Network Connections > SSH2_, in the tab _General_ does _Private keys_ contain `id_rsa`? If yes, you might try the alternative SSH client Apache MINA sshd instead: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TM9DBinKQdI&t=185s

Comment: @howlger Yes it does contain id_rsa.

Comment: @howlger Yes changing to Apache MINA sshd works! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure, in *Window > Preferences: General > Network Connections > SSH2* in the tab *General* that *Private keys* contains `id_rsa`.

Since Eclipse 2018-12 (which contains JGit/EGit 5.2) you can try in ***Window > Preferences: Team > Git*** to **switch** the **SSH client** from *JSch* **to *Apache MINA sshd*** ([see this video showing it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TM9DBinKQdI&t=185s)).

Answer (score 0):

This error would not occur with the [EGit 5.3.0 (Feb. 2019)](http://kishore)

> In the last release we had introduced a new SSH client based on the [Apache MINA sshd](https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/) library as an alternative to the JSch-based client.
>   **In EGit 5.3.0 the default settings are switched: by default, the Apache MINA implementation is used.**
>
> We plan to remove the old JSch SSH implementation completely in a future release of EGit.

Answer (score 0):

If someone not able to update it to Jsch (Like I am not able to do it in Spring Tool Suite) You may have to generate a new keypair using the -m PEM option like this:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM
```

so it can be used by Jsch.

Reference -
http://answers.neotys.com/questions/2218589-error-configure-git-connection-neoload-using-ssh-protocol-public-private-key